# Detect word by prefix only in SRGS grammar

Tags: grammar, speech-to-text, microsoft-speech-api

I'm using an SRGS grammar to refine accuracy of a Microsoft Speech STT service.
I have specific needs for this grammar because I would like it to match some words by prefix only, but get the whole word as a result of detection.

This is the kind of rule I tried:

`<rule id='test'>
    <item>
        contain<ruleref uri="grammar:dictation" type="application/srgs+xml"/>
    </item>
</rule>`

I would like this rule to match things like:
"contain", "contains", "containing"

Problem is the only things I get in vocal detection are like:
"contain and", "contain he"

This must be because I can't have both plain text ("contain") and the dictation tag defining a single word. STT assumes these will be 2 separate words and adapts the recognition result accordingly.

The `ruleref` tag referencing grammar:dictation is necessary in my case because if I use something like the "GARBAGE" special rule instead, I think I will not be able to fetch the whole word.

Any tips or ideas would be greatly appreciated, I'm afraid what I'm trying to do might be impossible in the current SRGS state.